# Sort file numerically and preserve blank lines between entries in Bash

Tags: bash, sorting, numerical, blank-line

I am currently struggling at sorting data. I searched online and never saw any topics mentioning my issue...

I have files with unordered data like:

```
1
blank line
3
blank line
2
```

Which have a blank line in between values. When I use my script, it effectively sorts data but blank lines are on top and values on bottom, like :

```
blank line
blank line
1
2
3
```

I would like to have an output like:

```
1
blank line
2
blank line
3
```

which preserves the structure of the input.

The command I use is: `sort -nk1 filename > newfile`

How can I preserve the blank lines in the right places?

Comment: Fundamentally, `sort` works on lines in isolation.  Each line is separate.  It cannot keep the structure you want.  You could do it with programs such as Perl, using its I/O to read the number and blank lines as a unit, and then sorting those units.  But plain `sort` can't do the job on its own.

Comment: `grep . filename | sort -nk1 | sed G` maybe?

Comment: You can do the job with a Perl one-liner: `perl -e '$/ = "\n\n"; print foreach (sort { $a <=> $b } <>);' data` (where `data` is the file containing the spaced data).  I wouldn't claim that is self-explanatory — it is anything but.  It is fairly compact, though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the empty lines, sort and add the empty lines again:

```
grep . filename | sort -nk1 | sed 's/$/\n/' > newfile
```

You can combine `grep` and `sed`

```
sort -nk1 filename | sed -n '/./ s/$/\n/p' > newfile
```

When you don't have an empty line after each data-line, you need to add some marker temporarily

```
tr '\n' '\r' < filename | 
  sed -r 's/([^\r]+)\r\r/\1\a\r/g;s/\r/\n/g' | 
  sort -nk1 | sed 's/\a/\n/g' > newfile
```